# Order of a distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

> Let $\delta_{j} \in D'(\mathbb{R})$ denote the dirac delta distribution at $j \in \mathbb{N}$ (which is defined as $\delta_j(\phi)=\phi(j) $ for any $\phi \in C^{\infty}_c$). Then, the order of the distribution $T_j=\frac{d^j \delta_j}{dx^j}$ is $j$.

I showed that the order is $\leq j$. I don't know how to prove the $\geq$ part. Can you provide a proof for that $\geq$ inequality?

Definition: Let $\Lambda \in D'(\Omega): \exists m \in \mathbb{N} \  \ \forall K \subset \Omega$ compact $\exists C>0: \forall \phi \in D_K=\{\phi \in C^{\infty}(\Omega):supp(\phi) \subset K \}$ it holds $|\Lambda(\phi)| \leq C p_m^K(\phi)$ where $p_m^K(\phi)=sup \{|D^{\alpha}\phi(x)|:x \in K, |\alpha| \leq m \}$ are the seminorms in $D_K$. The order of the distribution $\Lambda$ is the infimum over all such m.

Comment: So it seems it suffices to show that the dirac-delta is of order zero.

Comment: @ArcticChar   I know that the dirac delta has order 0, but how does that imply the answer?

Comment: I think in general, if $T$ is of order $k$, then $\partial^i T $ is of order $k+i$?

Comment: @ArcticChar Do you have a proof in mind for that ?

Comment: @ArcticChar Generically, but e.g. if $T$ is given by a smooth function, then $\partial_i T$ has order $0$ for all $i$. It's always the case that differentiation doesn't increase the order by more than $1$, but it may keep the order.

Comment: You have to show that one cannot estimate $|f^{(j)}(j)|$ by $c\sup\{|f^{(\ell)}(x):x\in\mathbb R,\, \ell\le j-1\}$ for all test functions $f$. Start with $j=1$ and assume that there is such a constant $c$. To get a contradiction you have to construct a test function $f$ with small values and large derivative at $1$.